# Embed image into exe

Tags: wpf, vb.net, expression-blend

I see that Blend 4 is not embedding the image to the EXE as WPF does. WPF will create "`/my_project;component/Images`" and the image will refer to its component. While inserting image in Blend, it will create "`pack://siteoforigin:,,,`" . Only file with size 250KB above will save the image to EXE. How to do this to every image?

Motive: When I go to production, I need to copy the debug folder. But the image is not placed in the running directory, instead in the solution. So running the debug only will result in a system crash as it cannot found the image.

Question: How to make Blend save every image to the EXE or by mean, the application component?

Comment: you add all the images you're referencing in XAML into your solution

Comment: Mind to explain a little more details?

Comment: WPF is creates an EXE... Don't add the image directly into the control, instead add an `Image` and set its `Source` to the file that you should be adding to your application. And usually you don't want to put a debug version of an EXE on a production machine unless its being used internally

Comment: FYI, this is information app that I build. Right now I,m doing 2 effort. First,create the animation,design in Blend. Then open VS2010 and add back the image resources to when I copy the exe, the image is embed to the exe. If taking from blend,no image embed to it..i hope u understand my explanation :)